# Flexbox is not perfecly centereing my NAV

Tags: html, css

[Here you can see its not perfectly centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yd4l.jpg)

My navigation wont center correctly horizontally while using flexbox as shown in the picture, ive tried everything i know to center it, but i cant seem to figure it out.

Could someone please help me? :D

```
        <header>
            <nav>
                <img class="Logo" src="images/Logo" alt="RPN Logo">
                <a class="nav_1" href="index.html">RPNorge</a>
                <a class="nav_2" href="regelverk.html">Regelverk</a>
                <a class="nav_3" href="spillerguide.html">Spillerguide</a>
                <a class="nav_4" href="whitelist.html">Søk Whitelist</a>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

nav > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0F0326;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 20px;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.Logo {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 125px;
    height: auto;
    order: 3;
    margin-bottom: -70px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.nav_1,.nav_2,.nav_3,.nav_4 {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav_1 {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

.nav_2 {
    order: 2;
    margin-right: 1rem;
}

.nav_3 {
    order: 4;
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

.nav_4 {
    order: 5;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Tried to center the NAV, did not work properly

Answer (score 0):

You mean vertical centering?
It's because you place elements to bottom:

```css
nav > a {
    ...
    align-self: flex-end;
```

just change it to:

```css
nav > a {
    ...
    align-self: center;
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the comment, i want it on the lower side :) the problem is that the whole nav+logo is a bit off horizontally, https://prnt.sc/zcrP8uPahfy- might be easier to see on that picture :)

Comment: Think i found out the problem, everything was centered, but since the texts on the right side was longer than the left side, the logo became uncentered, so i added some margin to the left side and it worked out :)